# How to clear bits using Bitwise Operators

Tags: c++, assembly, bit-manipulation

I'm interested in learning how to clear bits so that I can use part of the binary value, instead of the entire thing. What I hope to use this for is to obtain the signed bit, exponent, and the significand from an IEEE single precision float form.

However, I'm not entirely familiar with the hexadecimal system, and I was wondering if I could get your help.

Here are my thoughts so far: 
Signed bit - Bitwise-AND the binary value by 0x100000000 to get the first bit only

Exponent - Shift the value left once, and bitwise-and the new value by 0xFF000000 to obtain 
           the first eight bits for the exponent

Significand - Shift the value left 23 times

Since each of these will require doing work on the original value, I'm planning to also store the value into another register. That way, I can still do work on the value without "harming" the original. The value of the signed bit, exponent, and the signficand will then be stored into separate registers.

Comment: Ideally you want to shift right not left, but you are on the right track, mask and shift (AND and shift) is how you do it.  or shift then and whatever you prefer, does the same thing

Comment: It is very obvious that you are breaking the problem down into individual parts and asking how to do each thing on stackoverflow, and that is the right way to use stackoverflow.  I would highly recommend you do whatever it is you are doing in a language like C first (assuming you know C and it is something easier to write in) on your development machine, get all of your masking and shifting and other bit manipulation done, develop anywhere, run anywhere.  Once it performs the task properly then using that prototype then simply implement that code in assembly language.

Comment: Just a note: to get the most significant bit only, you should AND the value by 0x80000000.

Comment: Ideally simplifying the C code down to single operations, and/or operations that directly translate to single or a few lines of asm.

Comment: Also, I think it would be worth your time to bone up on the relationship of hexadecimal to bits.  Get some graph paper, and draw out what you intend to do.  Each hexadecimal digit corresponds to 4 consecutive bits, so mark "tick" marks every four bits.  Once you have your "map" on paper, it should be easy to see how mask values in hex map onto the fields in your number.  It'll save you time in the long run.

Comment: The most significant bit in a 32-bit value is worth 0x80000000 (not 0x100000000).  You know, you can find free calculators that can convert binary and decimal to/from hex for just about any OS you can name.  Windows, Ubuntu etc. ship them included.  Or google "online hex binary decimal calculator".  Linux normally ships with C headers with unions with bit-fields for parsing floating point values: try `grep mantissa /usr/include/*.h`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: I'm dealing with IEEE-754 single precission floating point format for this answer:

Sign: AND-mask your number with `0x80000000`. If result is 0, number is positive, else negative.
Exponent: AND-mask your number with `0x7F800000`, then shift 23 bits to the right.
Mantissa: AND-mask your number with `0x007FFFFF`.

To see why I have used these numbers, just convert each mask to binary form and place it under your binary representation of your floating point number:

```
SEEEEEEEEMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM = format of a floating point number: S=sign,
                                                                      E=exponent, 
                                                                      M=mantisa
10000000000000000000000000000000 = 80000000h  (isolate sign bit)
01111111100000000000000000000000 = 7F800000h  (isolate exponent, 8 bits)
00000000011111111111111111111111 = 007FFFFFh  (isolate mantissa, 23 bits)
```

To convert a binary number to hexadecimal, just arrange it in 4-bit groups and convert each group to an hexadecimal digit:

For example:

```
01111111100000000000000000000000 is arranged as:
0111 1111 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  which is translated into hex as this:
 7     F    8    0    0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's some NASM syntax 32bit

```
MOV eax, DWORD [ssValue]
MOV ebx, DWORD [signMask] ;; 80000000h
MOV ecx, DWORD [expoMask] ;; 7F800000h
MOV edx, DWORD [sigfMask] ;; 007FFFFFh
AND ebx, eax
AND ecx, eax
AND edx, eax ;; edx is the significand
SHR ebx, 31 ;; ebx is the sign
SHR ecx, 23 ;; ecx is the exponent
```

In C it would be something like

```
int sign = value & 0x80000000;
int expo = value & 0x7F800000;
int sigf = value & 0x007FFFFF;
sign >>= 31;
expo >>= 23;
```

**EDIT if you want to correct the exponent which has a 127 (7Fh) bias**

```
if(expo == 0x0) {
    // denormal
} else if(expo == 0xFF) {
    // +inf or nan depending on sigf
} else { // -126 to 127 range
    expo -= 0x7F;
}
```

**EDIT 2** 
In other languages like Java ">>" is a signed shift operator.

```
sign >>= 31; // would result in 0 or -1 (0xFFFFFFFF) if the sign bit was 1
sign >>>= 31; // would result in 0 or 1
```

Comment: You don't need to load 32-bit consts from memory!  `MOV ecx, 7F800000h` is a single instruction that's actually smaller than `MOV ecx, DWORD [expoMask]`.  Also, `and` allows 32-bit immediates as well so you can just use it directly.  And if you're going to right-shift, there's no point in masking away the low bits first, just `mov ebx, eax` / `shr ebx, 31` and you're done to get the sign bit as a 0 / 1.  (Or `sar` to get it as 0 / -1).  Another way to get the 8-bit exponent field is `rorx ecx, eax, 23` (BMI2) / `movzx eax, cl` (zero-extend the low 8 bits, with mov-elimination being possible.)

Answer (score 1):

In java, Bitwise XOR operation can be used to clear bit.
You can convert a specific from String to Integer using

I have written this function to clear the leftmost bit, irrespective of the sign.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(String.format( "-2 binary=%32s",Integer.toBinaryString(-2)));
    int dropped = toggleLeftMostBit(-2);
    System.out.println(String.format( "-2 dropped left bit val= %d\n   binary=%32s",dropped,Integer.toBinaryString(dropped)));

}


   private static int toggleLeftMostBit(int i)
{

    return  i ^  Integer.highestOneBit(i);

}
private static int toggleNthBit(int i, int n)
{
    return  i ^  1<< n-1;

}
```

Comment: What's the point of `Long.valueOf(Integer.toBinaryString`?  No need to convert to a string and back!!  That's very inefficient.  `highestOneBit(int)` [already returns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#highestOneBit(int)) an `int` with at most 1 bit set, exactly what you need to XOR with to clear the highest set bit, if there is one.  You're truncating back to `int` for the return value, so if this is some kind of attempt to sign-extend, it seems pointless unless I'm missing something. If so, please edit to explain why `i ^ Integer.highestOneBit(i)` wouldn't work

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the comment. I have corrected that part. It would have been residual of some other logic. However, Idea was to provide a line of logic, not the precise code. Not sure why would that attact a downvote.

Comment: Future readers that don't know the basics of bitwise operations won't know which parts are necessary and which parts are over-complicated irrelevant stuff, or inefficient ways to do things.  For example, this is still converting to a string and back instead of just casting `long iL = i;`  If that's to zero-extend instead of sign-extend, there are [cheaper ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53552476/224132) to do that, for example `((long)i) & 0xFFFFFFFFL`

Comment: @PeterCordes it seems that even casting to long is not required. Have made edits.