# Java - Copy integer to long

Tags: java

I have an external system outputting 2 unsigned integers that represent a 64 bit unsigned int. Java picks these up and converts them to signed integers.  I have called them lower and upper in java. I would like to put this back into a 64 bit int. I understand I have to use signed int which is ok.

I started off casting them both to long, shift the upper long by 32 bits and then trying to add them but it didn't go so well because the cast moves the sign bit of the integers. So I started to muck around with adding 2^31 and other messy stuff. How can I do this cleanly?

Here is an example, using 2 x 8 bit numbers to 16 bits for simplicity

`Higher = 00000000 lower = 11111111
Desired result
0000000011111111
Result I get
1000000001111111`

EDIT: This is code that I believe works ok (I haven't fully tested) but I was hoping for something cleaner.

```
private static long combineCounters(int lower, int upper) {
    long lower2 = (long)lower;
    if(lower2 < 0) lower2 += (2L<<31);
    long upper2 = (long)upper;
    if(upper2 < 0) upper2 += (2L<<31);
    long result = lower2 | (upper2<<32);
    return result;
 }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your case, first of all, you should store your integer values correctly into a long. To do so, you can AND your value with 0xFFFFFFFFL (a long with first 32 bit as 1).

Here is an example which works:

```
int upperInt = ...
int lowerInt = ...
long hi = upperInt & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
long lo = lowerInt & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
long c = (hi << 32) | lo;
System.out.println(String.format("0x%X", c));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int higher = ...
int lower = ...
long result = (((long) higher) << 32) | ((long) lower) & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
```

Comment: That doesn't give the correct result. For some reason, which I'm not quite sure, for 0 and -1 it gives 65535

Comment: That will fail also. You need to take into account that bit 32 gets moved to bit 64 when you convert from int to long. I was hoping there was a bitwise copy that could be done to avoid the mucking around

Comment: @MikeKulls Fixed it.

Comment: Interestingly that appears to work. I was expecting it to fail because you don't use & on the higher integer.

Comment: @MikeKulls you don't need to cut higher with `&` because `<<` push unwanted `1` outside.

Comment: We have no unwanted 1s. All bits are required to be kept.

Comment: @MikeKulls I mean when we extend `higher` to long we get sign bit extended to first 32 bits. I call that bits unwanted.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. I had made the wrong assumption all along of how the conversion would work. It doesn't move any bits, just fills in 1s for negative values.